# Remove a if contains a certain string Javascript not jquery

Tags: javascript

I have at least 4 buttons at 1 time

```
<a class="test" id="4" href="#">Browse</a>
<a class="test" id="5" href="#">Browse Catalogue</a>
<a class="test" id="6" href="#">Browse Albums</a>
<a class="test" id="7" href="#">Browse people</a>
```

I would like to remove or hide the one that only says "Browse". All others should still stay visible. Basically the non jquery of below. It needs to be pure JS.

```
 $('.test').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() == 'Browse';
}).hide();
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier backwards.

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
for (var el, i = 0; i < els.length; ++i) {
  el = els[i];
  if (el.innerHTML == 'Browse') {
    el.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. This worked. Thank you very much. 10 mins until i can accept.

Comment: @Graeme note, this will not work on old IE since it does not support `textContent` , it's easy to fix though.

Comment: You could also use filter on `els`, if you don't mind dropping some brother support, or implement filter on your as writen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: More complexity for less performance is not a trade-off I'd be willing to make ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take, if you'd like to keep the functional style of your code.

```
var tests = document.getElementsByClassName('test');

Array.prototype.filter.call(tests,function (elem) {
    return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText) === 'Browse';
}).forEach(function (elem) {
    elem.style.display = "none";
});
```

### [Working code](http://jsfiddle.net/QunpR/)

Comment: Note, array filter, and array forEach need shimming on older browsers.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.test').each(function () {
   if($(this).html()=='Browse'){
    $(this).attr("style", "display:none");
}
})
```